# How to set NULL values to a single character in IICS?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

There are 100+ incoming fields for a target transformation in IICS. NULLs can appear in any of these columns. But the end goal is to convert the NULLs in each of the incoming fields to `*` so that the data in the target consists of `*` instead of `NULL`.

A laborious way to do this is to define an expression for each column. That 100+ expressions to cover each and every column. The task of the expression is to convert `NULL` into `*`. But that is difficult in terms of maintenance.

In Informatica Power center there is a property on the target object that converts all the `NULL` values to `*` as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Tried setting the property `Replacement Character` on IICS for the target transformation. But that didn't help. The data is still coming in as NULL.

[image]

Do we have a similar functionality or property for target transformation on IICS? If so how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

i think i find easier to create a `reusable` exp transformation with 10 input and 10 putput. Then copy it 10 times for 100 fields.

1. create an input, output port like below -

```
in_col
out_col = IIF(isnull(in_col) OR is_spaces(in_col),'*',in_col)
```

2. Then copy in_col - 10 times. And copy out_col 10 times. You need to adjust/fix the formula though.
3. Save it and make it reusable'
4. Then copy that reusable widget 10 times.

This has flexibility - if formula changes, you just have to change only 1 widget and viola, everything changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Vertical macro](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-data-integration/current-version/transformations/transformations/expression-macros/vertical-macros.html). It allows writing a function that will affect a set of indicated ports. Follow the link for full documentation with examples.